# Contact us 404 error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make simple tabs. I am having trouble with the contact us tab. I keep getting a 404 error saying the page can not be found. I have copied some supposed to be working examples from online. I know the page exists because it is a email and i emailed it from my other email. This is my first time building a site. I am putting my PHP inside my html. I have tried making my file index.html and index.php and neither worked. It don't matter to me how i do it, ajax or php. I know i did not need to use jQuery to do what i am trying to do, but it was just easier for me. Thanks again for your help, it is much appreciated!

**jQuery**

```
$("#phillya11").click(function () {
$("#soon4").show();
$("#soon").hide();
$("#soon1").hide();
$("#soon2").hide();
$("#soon3").hide();    
$('#close4').click(function () {
    $("#soon4").hide();
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="phillya11"><a href="#"
style="text-decoration:none;color:  #FFF5ee">soon4</a>    </div> 
</div>
<div id="soon4">
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@myemail";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

**CSS**

```
#soon4{

display:none;
width:380px;
margin:25px;
height: 346px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size:1em;
background-color:#F10B78
}

#close4{
color: white;    
margin:90px    
}
```

Comment: Why is your `#close4` click function located inside of your `#phillya11` function? Also, `#close4` does not exist within your code.

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan a click on phillya11 bring up soon4 which would be my contact us tab.

Comment: Use classes better, instead of that `id`s mess!

Comment: @PhilFamme: dude, please use better names for your classes, names which describe what is the use of those elements or what they signify. That would be easier to understand for us, as well as you (down the line).

Comment: @Harsh lol yea there bad, sorry about that... will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you putting your PHP? In the index.html file or a separate file?

If you note on your form tag, you've defined the `action` as mail.php, which is a file that must exist for the form to post it's data to. This is probably where the 404 is coming from.

You can either leave your PHP in the index page (make sure you change it to index.php) and change the form `action` to index.php, or move your PHP code to a separate mail.php file.

Comment: i tried to put it in my html body and made it index.html and i tried index.php. I am really new i did not know i can make a mail.php file too. I will try to change the action now and see if that works

Comment: is it better to keep my code index.html and then every time i want to use php have it linked like you said mail.php or does it not matter to put the php in your html and name it index.php

Comment: I would say it just depends on your application. If you're going to re-use the mailing code, put it in it's own file. If you're only using it once, leaving it in the index is probably fine. Generally, though, it's probably best for readability and scaling to put it in it's own file. Let that file do the mailing, and redirect back to the index when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the event.preventDefault() in your click function.

```
$("#phillya11").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault()
$("#soon4").show();
//....
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/